# How to sync the data between two identical DB

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, mirroring

The thing is I've two identical databases, one is in my localhostserver at my laptop and the other one is on the office main server. Is there any automatic way or software that can synchronize the data between these 2 identical databases? I'm working with SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server Replication can ensure that your data is synchronized.  SQLRockstar is correct in saying that you need to determine if policy will allow the data to be stored on your laptop.

Questions to think about before moving ahead with replication:

1. How often is your laptop on the same network as your main server?
2. Do data modifications need to be two-way?  Do you just want your laptop to mimic the office server, or will you be making changes that need to be pushed back to the main server?
3. How big is your database expected to grow?  Will you have enough room on the laptop?
4. What happens if your laptop is lost/stolen/destroyed?  Will your data be safe?  Do you need to investigate in hard-drive level encryption (i.e. do you need to use bitlocker)?
5. How quickly do changes in one database need to be propagated to the other?

You may want to start off by investigating MERGE replication.

Comment: DataDog, my answets:

1. 98% of the time.
2. Yes need to be both ways. 
3. Yes i'll have enough room in my laptop.
4. I have 4 diferent secuirty levels to access my laptop's data.
5. Just as soon I change any DB it have to be merge to the other.

Thanxs a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to accomplish this, and each has its advantages and disadvantages. Before you sync anything you should talk to your DBA first, as there could be policies in place at your company that disallow having data be placed on portable devices such as a laptop.

Comment: we don't have much policies about informations, cause the data we register and manage its public. So I'll be ready to sync.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the server and your laptop to be updated and synced you can look into [transactional replication with updating subscribers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151794.aspx). This can be loosely looked as a two way replication.